# apply function after calling data response

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, vue.js, asynchronous

I want to apply slider function after calling API response,

this this my code

```
async getProducts () {

                let response = await axios.get('{{url("/")}}/api/products?new=1&limit=6&order=desc&sort=created_at');
                const products = response.data.data;
                this.products = products;
                let element = document.getElementById("sliderContainer");
                element.classList.add("regular");
                this.applySlider();
}
```

as you see i used async await but applySlider() function work before response?
what is my mistake? please, help me
Thanks in advance
 this is applySlider() function

```
applySlider() {
                if (this.products.length >= 1) {
                    $(".regular").slick({
                        //dots: true,
                        infinite: true,
                        slidesToShow: 4,
                        slidesToScroll: 4,
                        responsive: [
                            {
                            breakpoint: 992,
                            settings: {
                                slidesToShow: 3,
                                slidesToScroll: 3,
                                infinite: true,
                                dots: true,
                                arrows:false,
                            }
                            },
                            {
                            breakpoint: 768,
                            settings: {
                                slidesToShow: 2,
                                slidesToScroll: 2,
                                arrows:false,
                            }
                            },
                            {
                            breakpoint: 480,
                            settings: {
                                slidesToShow: 2,
                                slidesToScroll: 2,
                                arrows:false,
                            }
                            }
                        ]
                    });
                } 
            }
```

Comment: are you certain? It shouldn't be possible.

Comment: how to you know it is called before?

Comment: what should I do?

Comment: you should do your very best to confirm, for a fact, that `this.applySlider` actually runs before you get the response back. Set breakpoints or use `console.log` if you have to

Comment: what does applySlider do?

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki my slider run in my web page without images and the images appear in the bottom without sliding

Comment: show me the content of applySlider

Comment: try it with predefined  sliderContainer with `regular` class and see what happens. I mean hard code it in your html instead of creating them on the fly

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki It was before, but it didn't work, so I tried to change anything

Comment: try  $(".regular").slick({}) function with pre existing images in the page. do not get them from api, hard code them in html. maybe the problem is slick() function

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki it worked with me fine without API

Answer (score -4):

You can use **then** method.

The `then()` method returns a `Promise`. It takes up to two arguments: callback functions for the success and failure cases of the `Promise`.

---

Try something like this:

```
axios.get('{{url("/")}}/api/products?new=1&limit=6&order=desc&sort=created_at')
  .then(response => {
    // handle success
    const products = response.data.data;
    this.products = products;
    let element = document.getElementById("sliderContainer");
    element.classList.add("regular");
    this.applySlider();
  })
```

Minimal example:

```
axios.get('{{url("/")}}/api/products?new=1&limit=6&order=desc&sort=created_at')
  .then(response => {
    this.products = response.data.data;
    document.getElementById("sliderContainer").classList.add("regular");
    this.applySlider();
})
```

Check the full axios documentation [rigth here](https://github.com/axios/axios).

Comment: They are using `await` instead.